# Can Freeze(Hanging) happen in Thread-UnSafe Code that doesn't use Mutex, Semaphore, etc?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, freeze

My environment is an embedded Linux environment,
and I know that if Thread-UnSafety is used, a crash occurs.
Freeze can also occur?

Comment: Freezing the program could happen in dead-lock situations mostly.

Comment: If you have *undefined behaviour,* then there is no telling what is possible. Perhaps it's possible that a regiserized variable might facilitate an infinite loop, for example?

Comment: If your program invokes undefined behavior (which it is likely to do if you are using multiple threads in a non-thread-safe manner), then literally anything can happen, including freezing up.

Comment: @PKramer that article is about problems taht arise when there is synchronization between threads. OP is asking what happens when there is none

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I understood the question incorrectly then. Comment deleted

Answer (score 1):

Thread freezing can easily happen without invoking traditional synchronization objects, networking code for example. You issue a recv() but the remote end doesn't send anything. Your thread will just sit there waiting.

Comment: Unfortunately, my code only has one if statement using std::find.